# Converting String of Ints and Floats to Individual Ints and Floats in a CSV

Tags: string, csv, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape stock premarket data. Here is the code being used to scrape the website:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//body'):
        item = PremarketItem()
        item['volume'] = sel.xpath('//td[@class="tdVolume"]/text()').extract()
        item['last_price'] = sel.xpath('//div[@class="lastPrice"]/text()')[:30].extract()
        item['percent_change'] = sel.xpath(
        '//div[@class="chgUp"]/text()')[:15].extract() + sel.xpath('//div[@class="chgDown"]/text()')[:15].extract()
        item['ticker'] = sel.xpath('//a[@class="symbol"]/text()')[:30].extract()
        yield item
```

The output of the following code into the .csv file is something along the lines of this:

```
ticker,percent_change,last_price,volume
"HTGM,SNCR,SAEX,IMMU,OLED,DAIO","27.43%,20.39%,17.28%,17.19%,15.69%","5,298350,700,1090000,76320,27190,13010",etc
```

As you can see, the values are separated correctly, but they're all stuck in massive strings. I've tried multiple for loops, but nothing has worked, and I can't find anything. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting the massive strings you can fix the scrapy code so that the values are separated in the first place.

Your item XPaths start with // selecting all elements matching your specification and thus outputting all elements in one (massive) item. I suppose your target website has some structure with respect to the target items e.g. table rows.

Then you need to figure out a XPath expression that matches the rows and loop over those rows for parsing one item per row. See the following pseudo code:

```py
def parse(self, response):

    # Loop over table rows ... 
    for sel in response.xpath('//table/tr'):

        item = PremarketItem()
        # Use XPath starting in table row: Use dot at beginning
        item['volume'] = sel.xpath('./td[@class="tdVolume"]/text()').extract()
        # ... other fields ...
        yield item
```

See [scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#working-with-relative-xpaths) for examples of relative XPath expressions.